# Sorting line segment for routes

Tags: sorting, mapbox, graph-theory, arcgis, directed-graph

[image]

**notice**: red line overlaps with dark blue line  (it straight line in opposite direction) shown as curve for illustration

x1, y1 etc. are (start,end) latitude longitude pairs.

```
light blue segment(x1, y1 -> x2,y1)

dark  blue segment(x2, y1 -> x3, y3)

red        segment (x3, y3 -> x2, y4)
```

consider the array below which is in random order from which above map segment is drawn.

```
var arr = [

(x3, y3 -> x2, y4),
(x1, y1 -> x2,y1),
(x2, y1 -> x3, y3)

];
```

When plotted the array its plotted is correct order.

I want to sort the array in correct order from start to end following the route markers.

I could take one start,edn pair and then search the entire array again to find the inbound and outbound pair but thats inefficient.

What is most efficient way to sort the array considering some segments may run opposite direction.

Comment: Why not use a hashmap? Use start as key and end as value - this will allow you to build the route in O(n) instead of O(n^2)

Comment: @DavidWinder  but how do i figure out the start point, to start traversing the hashmap

Comment: i could start iterating the map, then use the value as key to search the map, if value exist for that key, indegree is 1 or more, that can't not be starting or ending point. After looping completes i will get start and end, 2 remaining value, but still which one of two is start?

Comment: if i use start as key and end as value, how do i store satellite data associated with the array